# Populate DropDown using Jquery and Object

Tags: jquery, html, json, object, drop-down-menu

I want to populate dropdown list options using object. e.g I have object as

```
 {"877":["email1@email.com"],"905":["email2@email.com"],"967":["email3@email.com"],"2":["email3@email.com","email5@email.com"]}
```

This dropdown will be dependent upon another dropdown, upon selection of company through dropdown, this email dropdown will populate according to selected company code. 877,905,967,2 are company codes.

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205559/populating-dropdown-menu-with-json-data?rq=1

Comment: var companies = {"877":["aaa"],"905":["bbb"],"967":["ccc"],"2":["ggg","ddd"]};

for (var text in companies) {
    var val = companies[text];
    $('<option/>').val(val).text(text).appendTo($('#selector'))
};

Answer (score 2):

I take it you want the contents of a second drop down to change depending on the contents of the first. If this is the case, I would do it as [follows](http://jsfiddle.net/dSRL2/1/):

**Html:**

```
Company code: <select id="cc"></select>
<br/><br/>
Email: <select id="email"></select>
```

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = {
        "877":["email1@email.com"],
        "905":["email2@email.com"],
        "967":["email3@email.com"],
        "2":["email3@email.com","email4@email.com"]};
    $("#cc").change(function() {
        $("#email").empty();
        $.map(data[$(this).children(":selected").val()],
            function(val) {
                $("#email").append($("<option></option>").val(val).html(val));
            });
    });
    for (var id in data) {
        $("#cc").append($("<option></option>")
                        .val(id).html(id));
    }
    $("#cc").trigger("change");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the faster solution but working:

**CODE:**

```
var obj = {
    "877": ["email1@email.com"],
        "905": ["email2@email.com"],
        "967": ["email3@email.com"],
        "2": ["email3@email.com", "email5@email.com"]
};


var select = $('<select></select>');
$.each(obj, function (index, val) {
    if (obj[index].length > 1) {
        $.each(obj[index], function(index2, val2){
            var option = $('<option value="' + index + '">' + val2 + '</option>');
            select.append(option[0]);
        });
    } else {
        var option = $('<option value="' + index + '">' + val + '</option>');
        select.append(option[0]);
    }
})
$('body').html(select);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/U3dMH/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
         var data = {
            "-- Select Date --":["-- Select Date First Then Slot --"],
            "06-Dec-2013":["10:00-12:00","2:00-4:00"],
            "07-Dec-2013":["14:00-16:00"]};

         $("#exmDtId").change(function() {
            $("#exmSlotId").empty();
            $.map(data[$(this).children(":selected").val()],
                function(val) {
                    $("#exmSlotId").append($("<option></option>").val(val).html(val));
                });
         });
         for (var id in data) {
            $("#exmDtId").append($("<option></option>")
                            .val(id).html(id));
         }

         $("#exmSlotId").append($("<option></option>")
                            .val("-- Select Date First Then Slot --").html("-- Select Date First Then Slot --"));

         //$("#exmDtId").trigger("change");
        });
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="30" align="center">
                                        <SPAN class="caption"><font color="red">*</font> </SPAN>
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="220">
                                        Exam Date
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="350">
                                        <select id="exmDtId"></select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="30" align="center">
                                        <SPAN class="caption"><font color="red">*</font> </SPAN>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        Exam Batch
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select id='exmSlotId' name='exmSlot'></select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
</table>
```